# What is the logic of "This weekend"? Does it refer either to the previous weekend or the following weekend.?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

[Look at this page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weekend)

> 2. regular events British English speakers say that something takes place at weekends.
>
> The beach gets very crowded at weekends.
>
> American speakers usually say that something takes place weekends or
>   on weekends.
>
> He often studies evenings and weekends.
>
> On weekends I usually sleep late.
>
> 3. single events
>
> You can say that an event takes place during a particular weekend.
>
> Will you be visiting relatives during the holiday weekend?
>
> On a weekday, the weekend or this weekend can refer either to the
>   previous weekend or the following weekend. You can use at, during, or
>   over in front of the weekend. Don't use any preposition in front of
>   this weekend.
>
> Her new film came out at the weekend.
>
> I'll call you over the weekend.
>
> My birthday was this weekend.
>
> We might be able to go skiing this weekend.

Here is what I understood, suppose that today is Tuesday & I say:

*Her new film came out at the weekend.* (the previous weekend, ie 4 days ago)

*I'll call you ạt the weekend.* (the following weekend., ie that will happen in 4 days)

*Her new film came out this weekend.* (the previous weekend, ie 4 days ago)

does "*Her new film came out this weekend.*"="*Her new film came out last weekend.*"?

*I'll call you this weekend.* (the following weekend., ie that will happen in 4 days)

**Am I misunderstanding something?**

Comment: Seems like you have it right. What is bothering you about it?

Comment: I hear a lot of people say "Her new film came out ~over~ the weekend" to refer backwards.

Comment: @Jim, so "I call you the following weekend after this weekend"="I call you in 13 days" (today is Tuesday)

Comment: @Tom, in your reply to Jim, native speakers, in my part of the UK, would say 'I'll call you the weekend after next'. In practice people often, in the UK at least, add a clarifying word if there is any potential for confusion about what weekend is being discussed 'this weekend coming' or 'the weekend just passed' for example.

Answer (score 3):

"This weekend" can refer to both the previous or following weekend, based on the tense of the sentence. If the sentence is written in **past tense**, "this weekend" generally refers to the previous.

> Her new film **came out** *(past tense)* this weekend. (the previous weekend)

If the sentence is written in **future tense**, "this weekend" generally refers to the next weekend.

> I **will call** *(future tense)* you this weekend. (the following weekend)

Comment: so,"her new film came out this weekend"="...last weekend"?

Comment: @Tom Yes. Since the sentence uses "came", which is in past tense, it means that the film has _already come out_. This can only be true if "this weekend" refers to _the last weekend_ and not _the next weekend_.

Comment: what a weird usage! is it common to say like that  "Her new film came out (past tense) this weekend."?

Comment: @Tom No it isn't, I wrote the words (past tense) in brackets to indicate that the verb phrase **"came out"** is the carrier of the tense in this sentence. If the sentence was "Her new film **will come out** this weekend.", it would refer to the **next weekend**, since "will come out" is the **future tense** of "came out".

Comment: @Tom I agree it is weird.  Her new film came out last weekend is what I would say.  It gets worse if the word next is used, on a Thursday or Friday.  Does it mean this coming weekend or the weekend 10 days from now?   Always verify, especially about picking someone up at the airport.

Comment: @Tom - It’s no different than saying “Her book came out in October”  and “Her book comes out in October”

Comment: @Tom: Imagine telling a coworker on monday "I went to see a movie this weekend". The tense you are using reveals that you are implicitly saying "this [past] weekend". It is omitted because it is already clear from context, as you are using past tense.